# data fetch pattern for EAI Content Enricher

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7, ionic4

I'm saving settings of a page in the local storage. Works just fine.

```
const settings = [amount, hours]
localStorage.setItem('settings', JSON.stringify(settings));
```

Now, the same service class should return only the the `amount`. Now, of course, that returns a promise. Fine, but I want to decompose the data set of `amount` and `hours` first to return only the `amount`. Something like this: (of course this is not gonna work because the function is finished while the async data fetch is still in process).

```
public getAmount(){
    this.storage.get('settings').then((settings) => {
      console.log('SettingsService: settings=' + settings[0]);
      this.amount= settings[0];
    });

    return this.amount;
  }
```

Anyhow, what is best-practice or a pattern to handle such a data decomposition?

- also returning a new promise from this function or ..
- simply return a number, i.e. the `amount`.

If I think of the [EAI pattern Content Enricher](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/DataEnricher.html) that gathers data from different source, to compose a smarter return value, one also needs to block before all partial data has arrived. So, how do we block the data fetch in JavasScript respectively TS/Angular?

Thanks for sharing your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I see at least two things:
1) Why are you saving your data in array: `[amount, hours]`? It would be much better to create a model interface, and store it in object (not array):

```
export interface Settings {
   amount: Amount; // or maybe number - choice is yours?
   hours: number;
}
```

2) Once you have model, then it will be really straight forward. You should rather use Observable instead of Promises. Once you have Observable  - it's really easy to map settings to amounts:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';

var observableFromPromise =  from(promiseSrc);
public getAmount(): Observable<Amount> {
    from(this.storage.get('settings')).pipe(
        map((settings: Settings) => settings.amount)
    );
}
```

Then you will be able to use amount value in template or in another component/service

```
// create observable field in component.ts
public amount$: Observable<Amount> = service.getAmount();

// use in component.html
<p>{{amount$ | async}}</p>

// or use in component.ts
this.amount$.subscribe(amount => console.log('this is the amount:', amount));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer about rxjs, Pawel. I understand the data modelling. I don't understand yet how that is blocking while gathering data from other source. I need programm a snippet to test that now. I'm getting back to this thread.

Comment: could one also bind these amount$ observable to a rective form to be constantly updated both ways? (changes could appear in the local storage as well as in the input field).

Comment: If you have `update()` method, there are at two ways. First one - use `valueChanges` from FormControl ->`control.valueChanges.subscribe(value => this.service.update(value));`. But it might not be the best way, as the value in the control might not be in correct state (eg. invalid), or you don't wanna to overload your browser with such subscription (each change inside the control would cause `this.service.update(...)` to be called). From my point of view, it would be best to hit the method when you are submitting the form (eg. clickign a button) with: `this.service.update(control.value)`